# ngIf show or hide in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have function in `component.ts` like below

```js
    visability=true;
    showTextBox(){
      debugger;
      this.visability = false;

    }
```

and in `component.html` below code I have

```html
       <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox"  class="check">
            <!-- (click)="show=!show" -->
            <b class="b switch" ></b>
            <b class="b track"></b>
          </div>
          <h4 id="door-delivery">Door Delivery</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm address">
          <div *ngIf="!visability" (click)="showTextBox()">
            <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Enter Address">
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="visability" (click)="showTextBox()">
            <select formControlName="pickup_location" class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-city" data-live-search="true" required>
              <option data-tokens="" disabled>
                <h2>Pickup location...</h2>
              </option>
              <option data-tokens="India">
                <h2>India</h2>
              </option>
              <option data-tokens="UAE">
                <h2>UAE</h2>
              </option>
              <option data-tokens="Japan">
                <h2>Japan</h2>
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My Toggle [Looks like](https://codepen.io/RammmohanBandaru/pen/BPXzmv)
My Question is when I click on toggle it should appear Enter pickup location and as well as again if I click on toggle it should be display the list of cities.

How we can achieve this? could any one help me

Comment: In your function instead of setting visibitlity to false you can just set it to the opposite of what it currently is with `!` operator.  `visibility = !visibility`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `click` on your div holding toggle button as:

```
<div class="toggle" (click)=toggleTextBox()>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="check">
    <b class="b switch" ></b>
    <b class="b track"></b>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
visability=true;
toggleTextBox(){
  this.visability = !this.visability;
}
```

no need of `(click)="showTextBox()"` in div under `<div class="col-sm address">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly in your template :

```
(click)="visability = !visability"
```

Comment: It is important to respect the space before and after the `=`. Can you try to move it on the parent `<div>`?